# how to logout siteminder session from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, logout, siteminder

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 application that is using site-minder for Web SSO authentication. I have a log-out functionality in the application where a user can click the "logout" button. I am abandoning/removing/clearing the session in the button's event handler. Plus I am also clearing all cookies to drop the session. However since the application uses siteminder for authentication, the session is not really getting dropped. After clicking logout, if user navigates to any page then the session still gets created (which it gets from siteminder) without redirecting the user to WebSSO login page.

Please can you advise how can I drop the siteminder session upon logout? Is there any siteminder specific configuration changes at the application/IIS/siteminder level that I need to make to make it work?

Any help highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple. After destroying your own session, you just have to redirect the user to the logout url configured on the siteminder authentication server.

Comment: In our case we created a "signout" action that did it's thing (cleared FedAuth cookies, etc) and then redirected to the SiteMinder "logout" route, which then redirected back to our main target page.

Answer (score 0):

The logout/logoff URI needs to be configured in the AgentConfigObject of the WebAgent that is protecting the application.